# Chromium web-app creation doesn't work in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, chromium, webapps

If you create an application of a website in Chromium and choose "desktop", a .desktop file is created. In 12.04, you were able to move it to ~/.local/share/applications/ and then start it from the Dash or the launcher. 
In my fresh 12.10 installation, this doesn't work anymore.
I think the line that is misinterpreted is `Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --app=http://buymeapie.com/`. If you try to run it from a terminal, you get the following result:

> 20:32 ~ speter > Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --app=http://buymeapie.com/
>   bash: --app=http://buymeapie.com/: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

(English: "*File or directory not found*").

Can anyone explain or knows a workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is within the file Chromium creates. Using your example, this is the .desktop it creates:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Buy Me a Pie! - Lista de Compras
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --app=http://buymeapie.com/
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=chrome-http___buymeapie.com_
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=buymeapie.com
```

the problem is in the first line, the "shebang line" and the desktop entry definition should be in two different lines

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
(...)
```

So this should be a Chromium bug. To correct this, you only have to open the .desktop created with a text editor and add a new line between those two lines.

PS: The Exec line is correct: if you execute `/usr/bin/chromium-browser --app=http://buymeapie.com/` in a terminal the  website is shown.

Comment: Note that if you chose menu instead of desktop when creating the application, the file will be found here: ~/.local/share/applications/