# Chrome/Chomium Application Shortcuts Broken with 12.10

Tags: 12.10, google-chrome, chromium, webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chromium web-app creation doesn’t work in 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207283/chromium-web-app-creation-doesnt-work-in-12-10)

Chrome/Chromium allows you to turn a web page into a "desktop application" (tools->create application shortcut). This creates a desktop icon and or a menu item (you get to choose) that when launched will start a standalone instance of that web page. No URL bar, the alt-tab switcher icon is the web page's favicon, etc.

This was all great with 12.04. I recently installed 12.10 from scratch and these application shortcuts no longer work. They are neither in the menu, nor clickable from the desktop (they are text files on the desktop).

I understand that 12.10 has tried to integrate web apps more deeply, but perhaps in doing so they broke the already pretty good feature supplied by chrome.

Does anybody know how to re-enable this?