# Webapps don't open correctly when using Chromium

Tags: chromium, window, webapps

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 completely fresh, the old version of Ubuntu was discarded or overwritten (or whatever you call it). I want to use the Ubuntu webapps with  Chromium but I've had several problems.

}The first problem is that Chromium won't ask me if I want to install a webapp if I go to a supported site (and I don't already have the webapp installed). 
The second problem is that when I install the webapp by visiting the site in Firefox, and then I try to open it in Chromium, Ubuntu will open a completely new Chromium icon and window in the Launcher, and the icon will be labeled "Untitled"; also there is no search bar in the new window, only the tab at the top.

I've tried using several webapps with Firefox set as the default browser and they work as expected: once the webapp icon is clicked a Firefox window is opened on the Firefox launcher icon, and the window has 'new tab' button and search bar.

Comment: Chromium>Menu>Tools>Create applications and shortcuts. It will do 99% the same as a "Webapp" except for the Unity integration.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work anymore in 12.10. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/207283/chromium-web-app-creation-doesnt-work-in-12-10 for details.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the 'Unity WebApp extension for the chromium browser' installed? If not, go to the Software Center -> Technical Items (or just search in Synaptic). I had to install it to get Chromium working correctly.